# When the leaf length ranges are given in a plant species' description, what do the numbers in parentheses represent?

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy, morphology

Referring to a plant species, a paper I am reading (see citation below) says: "Blades are 4–5(6) mm long and (0.5)1–1.5 mm broad."
I understand the numbers 4-5 and 1-1.5 would be the ranges, but what do the numbers 6 and 0.5 in the parentheses represent?

Domínguez, Y., Valdés, C. M. P., & de Miranda, V. F. O. (2012). New features of Cuban endemic Pinguicula filifolia (Lentibulariaceae) and considerations on its habitat and ecology. Flora-Morphology, Distribution, Functional Ecology of Plants, 207(11), 838-841.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you see this being used in terms of a range...

- the numbers *outside* the parentheses represent the *normal* or expected range, and
- the numbers *inside* the parentheses represent *atypical* extensions beyond the normal range that are uncommon but possible and recorded.

Radford, Ahles, and Bell's 1968 flora, *Manual of the Vascular Flora of the Carolinas* confirms this in its preface (page vii):

> In instances where most measurements for a character fall within one part of the total range of variation, the more infrequent or extreme size range is given in parenthesis as an extra measurement: e.g., "leaves 4-8 (16) cm wide", not "leaves 4-16 cm wide."

So, in your example, you can interpret the first range as follows:

- Blades are typically 4-5 mm long (but sometimes 6 mm long) and typically 1-1.5 mm broad (though sometimes only 0.5 mm broad).

---

<sup>Radford, A.E., Ahles, H.E. and Bell, C.R., 1968. *Manual of the vascular flora of the Carolinas*. Univ of North Carolina Press.</sup>